# Javascript/jQuery: How to increment a number and highlight text when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched and search, but cannot find what I need. I know very little about Javascript so I need a bit of help with this.

I have a number, say numValue, that I want to increase or decrease based on items being selected in different areas. Plus I want those items to highlight and stay highlights until clicked again. When selected I want numValue to decrease by 1 and when deselected I want numValue to increase by 1.

Example:

**50** (numValue)

Group 1

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

Group 2

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

So if I click on Group 1/Option 1 and Option 2 plus Group 2/Option 3 I want the numValue to decrease by 3 (for 3 selected options). I want each item to stay selected when clicked not deselect when another option is clicked. Then deselect when clicked a second time. So it becomes:

**47** (numValue)

Group 1

- **Option 1**
- **Option 2**
- Option 3

Group 2

- Option 1
- Option 2
- **Option 3**

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have some HTML and maybe some Javascript or jQuery even if it doesn't work?

Comment: How about 'multiple' attribute for select list?

Comment: The code I had a deleted in frustration. Basically my code was going from 50 to 49 but when it added it back it went from 49 to 51. I believe it was because I was missing the if statments like Josh and GregL used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/2NJNT/

Basically, I'd just put all the logic in the class attribute.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="selector">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
    <li>Qux</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.selector .chosen{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    var selector = $('ul.selector'),
        numValue = 0,
        HIGHLIGHT_CLASS = 'chosen';

    selector.on('click', 'li', function () {
        var src = $(this);

        if (src.hasClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS)) {
            src.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS);
            numValue--;
        } else {
            src.addClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS);
            numValue++;
        }
    });

});
```

**Legacy jQuery (< 1.7)**

```
$(function () {
    var numValue = 0,
        HIGHLIGHT_CLASS = 'chosen';

    $('ul.selector').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
        var src = $(this);

        if (src.hasClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS)) {
            src.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS);
            numValue--;
        } else {
            src.addClass(HIGHLIGHT_CLASS);
            numValue++;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. Seeing examples and seeing how they work helps me a ton.

Comment: Note that Josh's code uses the new `.on()` method introduced in jQuery 1.7, so you need to be using that version (or later, when the next version gets released).

Comment: @GregL True. This can be swapped out for [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) pretty easily though.

Comment: @Josh Good point. I wasn't saying it was a bad thing, I was just making clear which version of jQuery it was reliant on. 1.7 is still quite new, so not everyone has updated yet, so it is worth explicitly noting if your answers rely on it for now.

Comment: @Josh I was going to come here and ask about this code not working in the latest Firefox, but I see you updated  the code a bit. After updating to what you included it works in Firefox.

Comment: Oh, yeah I was using `srcElement`, but should've been using `target` or letting jQuery handle this. I chose the latter option.

Comment: @Josh - Would I be able to implement jquery cookies with this to save the state of the class being added? You can point me in the right direction instead of writing out the code if you prefer. I am throwing this all together here if it helps. http://skyrimperks.com/calculator

Comment: Checkout [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for an overview and [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for an easy to use implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example using checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/D6CP4/1/

I have used the following HTML code for each group (feel free to change this, it was just an example):

```
<div class="group">
    <span class="header">Group 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="group1_1" /><label for="group1_1">Option 1</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="group1_2" /><label for="group1_2">Option 2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="group1_3" /><label for="group1_3">Option 3</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript, which utilises jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   var numValue = 50;
    $('.group :checkbox').click(function() {
       var $cb = $(this);
        if ($cb.is(':checked')) {
            numValue -= 1;
            $cb.closest('li').addClass('highlight');  
        } else {
            numValue += 1;
            $cb.closest('li').removeClass('highlight');
        }
        $('#numValue').text(numValue); // show the value on the page
    }); 
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: +1 You got fancy and added a far more appropriate set of checkboxes :)

Comment: Thanks GregL for this example. With this and Josh's example I can do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

well you can give all of your desired elements a set class name, for example "select" and define a highlight class in your css, and then use something like this :

```
var numValue=50;
$(".select").click(function(){
if(this.data("selected")){
numValue +=1;
$(this).data("selected",false).toggleClass("highlight");
}else{
numValue -=1;
$(this).data("selected",true).toggleClass("highlight");
}})
```

[EDIT] i've used the following bits from jquery : http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/data/

let me know if you need explanation for the code